# Memory Leaks while using MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send a CSV file through MfMail Composer.Everything works fine but there are lot leaks while using Instruments.I am not able trace out where I went wrong.Here is my code.

```
-(NSData *)getCSV
{
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [(ETAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSMutableArray *expensesList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
for(int i = 0;i<[results count];i++){
    NSString *category = [[results objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"category"];
    NSString *date = [[NSDateFormatter dateFormatterwithMediumStyle]stringFromDate:[[results objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date"]];
    NSString *amount = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[[results objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"amount"] numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",category,date,amount ];
    [expensesList addObject:mailString];
}
NSString *expensesString = [expensesList componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
NSData *expensesData = [expensesString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return expensesData;
}


-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
NSData *csvFile = [self getCSV];
NSString *csvFileName = @"MyExpenses";
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailController setSubject:@"List Of Expenses"];
[mailController setMessageBody:@"Expenses" isHTML:NO];
[mailController addAttachmentData:csvFile mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:csvFileName];
[mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I see anything in the code you've provided that should cause you to leak. Your leaks are likely taking place elsewhere.

What I do see, however, is the potential to create *a lot* of autoreleased objects in that loop in `-getCSV`, and depending on how many iterations you're performing, that could be almost as bad. The way you've written it, I see a date formatter and three strings headed for your main autorelease pool with every iteration. One suggestion is to create a date formatter outside your loop that you can reuse inside it. Another suggestion is to frame the guts of your loop with a local autorelease pool; that will prevent your main autorelease pool from becoming too large.

Apropos of nothing, you should also consider using fast enumeration.

Here's your loop with the suggestions applied:

```
NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatterWithMediumStyle];

NSMutableArray *expensesList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
for (id obj in results)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *category = [obj valueForKey:@"category"];
    NSString *date = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:[obj valueForKey:@"date"]];
    NSString *amount = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[obj valueForKey:@"amount"] numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", category, date, amount];

    [expensesList addObject:mailString];

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.And yes i just removed the code and checked  and the memory leaks are still there.do you any idea about where these leaks can possibly be...because i am getting these leaks once the mail is sent.

Comment: @Chandubhai Without seeing more of your code, it would be difficult for me to say. The only question I can think of is: What are you doing with that instance of `NSData` you're returning from `-getCSV`? I mean, I can see what you're doing with it as far as `-displayComposerSheet' is concerned. Could you be retaining it somewhere else somehow, and failing to release it?

Comment: No thats the only method i am using it in.

Comment: @Chandubhai You said the leaks occur after you send the mail. What's happening in that area? (As I mentioned earlier, seeing more code might be of help.)